# Добавление записи в бд при помощи mysqli

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Подскажите, как добавить информацию в бд при помощи mysqli, способ снизу не работает

> $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO pages
> (title,url,text,description,keywords)
> VALUES ('".$title."', '".$url."',
> '".$text."','".$description."','".$keywords."')")
> or die ('Ошибка #3872683872');

Answer (score 2):

А ну быстро читать документацию!

http://www.php.net/mysqli

У вас вообще код *только подготавливает* запрос.

Answer (score 0):

что выводится?
Что происходит, что за глупые вопросы задаются.

```
    If ($sql) $db->execute(); 
             else echo "Ошибка #3872683872";
```

И не будет работать, правильно пишет читай доки. Там же русским языком все написано. Подготовить, отправить, дополнить запрос. **Всем все делать лень**!!!